# Install SSIS on my system without sql server

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I want to install SSIS on my system so that I can check a package execution without sql server.

Can anybody tell me is it possible? and if it is possible can you guys please share the link from where I can get the setup of SSIS.

I don't want to install Sql server as this package will be running on few machines which doesnot have sql server

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You still need a SQL Server licence. It's not a good idea to deploy SSIS runtimes to user computers

Comment: Then what's the good idea, deploying SSIS on server where we are deploying build.

Comment: Also m not able to find the setup for ssis

Comment: If you _already_ have SQL Server installed and you have packages running on it (packages that are deployed to the catalog), then you hsould be able to install the client tool, SQL Server Management Studio, connect to the SSIS catalog and inspect package execution status, logs, schedules, parameters through that client tool

Comment: You can download the free version of SSMS (Express) here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351 I'm not sure if it lets you do all the SSIS management stuff though